# How to make a dataset with a datatable in it and read the datatable from the dataset in an actionresult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dataset

I have been searching for an answer to this for a couple of days, problem is that everything I search for give me only the answer to a reversed version of my problem or result in creating more problems then I had to begin with.
This is probably answered multiple times to but the search-ability is not that great, but here goes:

I am working in a mvc.asp.net application.

I have two insert into database one for excel and one for csv, both works, but now I need to split up both of them into three parts each. Second part so that the users can themselves map columns from the sheets to the database table column names as the different rows will go to different datatables that I later add to a sql database table in part 3, I already have the code for that but only need to copy it over, my problem is this:

I need a DataSet for my DataTable so that I can move the datatable from one actionresult to another.
I have tried the Xml version of this but it did not work.

So I just want to know how to make a dataset with a datatable in it and then get the dataset in another actionresult, and then get the datatable out of it, how do I do this?

(Also but this is a side question and I can ask it in another question if it is a problem, but it is relevant in the case of the excel version, I have a string fileExstension that check what type the document is, xls or xlsx that needs to be included and the file path to the actual excel file. Can I include this in the DataSet or do I need to use another method to move those?)

(Comments to myself are in Swedish. Please excuse that.)
Current Excel version code:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Xml;

namespace BFProj2.Controllers
{
    public class ExcelImportController : HomeController
    {
        // GET: Import
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            if (file != null && Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);
                if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["File"].FileName;
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                    }
                    Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);





                    //response redirect till ny controller
                    //i ny controller, använd Session["aMuze.fileLocation.Excel"] för att hämta filnamnet

                    //Flytta till ny controller.
                    string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                    //Jet providern ska automatiskt kolla om det är en HDR eller inte.
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                    {
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }





                    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    if (dt == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    List<string> ourColumns = new List<string>();

                    //loopa innehållet från varje fält i första raden och lägg in det i ourColumns
                    ourColumns.Add("HEJ");

                    //TODO: Ändra fileLocation i XmlWriteMode och XmlReadMode samt lägg till en ny version av den typen.


                    DataSet exceldata = new DataSet();
                    //TODO: Add fileLocation
                    //TODO: Add fileExstension
                    exceldata.Tables.Add(ds);

                    Session["aMuze.fileLocation.Excel"] = fileLocation;

                    //
                    //
                    //Borde vara här som man bryter och skickar vidare till nästa actionresult?
                    //
                    //

                    String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int t = 0;

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        t++;
                    }
                    //TODO:Lägga till varje column så att dom kan flyttas till vyn innan dom flyttas till denna innläggning i databasen.
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                    string query = string.Format("Select * from [Sheet 1$]", excelSheets[0]);
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    }




                    if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
                    {
                        string FileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(FileLocation);
                        }
                        Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                        xmlreader.Close();

                        //Här börjar inläsningen i Databasen.
                        //Flytta till tredje controller.
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Change row name if the table referred to is different - Users( , , , )
                        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
                        //Ska ställas i rätt ordning, Titel, FirstName, LastName, Email, AbstrNum, PosterTitel, Workshop
                        string query2 = "Insert into Users(Titel,FirstName,LastName,Email,AbstrNum,PosterTitle,Workshop,Keywords,Institution,LastActivityDate)Values('" + ds.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][3].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][4].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][5].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][6].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][7].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][8].ToString() + "','" + time.ToString(format) + "')";

                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MappaColumner(DataTable ds/*HttpPostedFileBase fileLocation, DataSet exceldata, string Filterfile, string fileExtension*/)
        {
            //Session["aMuze.fileLocation.Excel"] = fileLocation;
            //TODO: Än så länge så är bara string Filterfile och string fileExstension där som platshållare.
            //TODO: Få ut DT - ds.

            //  for (int y = 0; y < ds.Columns.Count; y++)
            //{ }

            /*String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int t = 0;

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        t++;
                    }
                    //TODO:Lägga till varje column så att dom kan flyttas till vyn innan dom flyttas till denna innläggning i databasen.
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                    string query = string.Format("Select * from [Sheet 1$]", excelSheets[0]);
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    }




                    if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
                    {
                        string FileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(FileLocation);
                        }
                        Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                        xmlreader.Close(); */


            // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Message = "The Import was a success" });
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult EndResult ()
        {
            /*for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Change row name if the table referred to is different - Users( , , , )
                        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
                        //Ska ställas i rätt ordning, Titel, FirstName, LastName, Email, AbstrNum, PosterTitel, Workshop
                        string query2 = "Insert into Users(Titel,FirstName,LastName,Email,AbstrNum,PosterTitle,Workshop,Keywords,Institution,LastActivityDate)Values('" + ds.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][3].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][4].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][5].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][6].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][7].ToString() + "','" + ds.Rows[i][8].ToString() + "','" + time.ToString(format) + "')";

                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close(); */

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Current model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace BFProj2.Models
{
    public class DataSetModel
    {
        DataSet csvdata { get; set; }
        DataSet exceldata { get; set; }
        string fileExstension { get; set; }
        string fileLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-webgrid-in-mvc-4-using-simple-model-and-data/ . Also, please read up on the MVC design pattern

Comment: So I need to create a whole model just to pass a dataset from one actionresult to another?

Comment: that's the MVC design-yes much like sending an object of type (yourTable) to another method. you send the model. Either that or using ViewData, but the first is better practise.

Comment: Okay, but how do I get the actual datatable from the actionresult to the model if I need to make a dataset to move the datatable?

Comment: create your dataset,( with get set properties) then use something like `(insertDatasetName) data = new (insertDatasetName)();` then you can do `data.someproperty =...`

Comment: And now, how do I return it in my actionresult(not in the actionresult view but at the start of the actionresult)?

Comment: do you mean `public ActionResult myactionName(<insertClassModelName> varName){`

Comment: Thanks, it is the right one, but it is not working?

Comment: what do you mean by *it is the right one*? also, what isn't working?

Comment: Got it working in the csv version, meant that the code was what I wanted, though seems it worked just writing in 'DataTabel csvData' instead in the csv Data Importer and what it is that is not working is the same code in the Excel version. Or do you want me to add the code?

Comment: it all depends on how the data is coming in from the excel version, as it may need to be 'tweaked' to a 'readable' format. Adding the code would be helpful, though.

Comment: I don't actually speak/read (Swedish?) but try strpping through your code to ensure the dataset gets filled in the excel version

Comment: Have you seen [this?](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1267/entry-3238-c%23-and-mvc3-uploading-and-parsing-an-excel-document-is-easier-than-it-seems/)

Comment: Thank you, it looks like what I needed. The Swedish is just for commenting to myself about where to cut it into parts and what is needed to be changed later on.